# Point coverage in randomly chosen interval

Tags: probability

Need a little nudge in the right direction

Let $L$ and $R$ be randomly chosen interval endpoints having arbitrary joint distribution, but, of course, $L \leq R$. Let $p(x) = Pr\{L \leq x \leq R\}$ be the probability the interval covers the point $x$, and let $X = R - L$ be the length of the interval. Establish the formula: $E[X] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(x)dx$

Any help would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A nudge: think Fubini.

Comment: Second nudge (if I may, @Byron... :-)): $X=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbf 1_{A(x)}dx$ for some events $A(x)$ depending on $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we need to apply Fubini's Theorem:

By definition,
$$ \mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}[\,\int_{L(\omega)}^{R(\omega)}1\cdot\mathrm{d}x\,]= \int_{\Omega}\mathbb{d}p\cdot \int_{L(\omega)}^{R(\omega)}1\cdot\mathrm{d}x=\int_{\Omega}\mathbb{d}p\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1_{[L(\omega),\,R(\omega)]}\mathrm{d}x=\\ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}x  \int_{\Omega}1_{[L(\omega),\,R(\omega)]}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathbb{P_r}\{L\le x\le R\}\mathrm{d}x $$
The above is the desired result.(Note when using Fubini's Theorem, you need make sure $\mathbb{E}X$ exists)

Comment: How is Fubini's theorem applied here, maybe is just my ignorance, but I cannot see the relation with product spaces. Is this just related to iterated integrals?

Comment: Here we use Fubini's Theorem(interchange the order of integration):$\int_{\Omega}\mathbb{d}p\cdot \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}1_{[L(\omega),\,R(\omega)]}\mathrm{d}x=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{d}x  \int_{\Omega}1_{[L(\omega),\,R(\omega)]}\mathrm{d}x$

Comment: thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: Funny: none of the four intermediate formulas is correct, for some reason or another.

Comment: Would you please clarify one of them(may be the "most" incorrect one)? But I think the idea(apply Fubini) is not wrong. I am a newcomer here. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure, the first one can be rewritten as $\mathbb E(Z(\omega))$ for some specific random variable $Z:\Omega\to\mathbb R$. This is incorrect. One can write either $\mathbb E(Z)$ or $\int\limits_\Omega Z\mathrm d\mathbb P$ or $\int\limits_\Omega Z(\omega)\mathrm d\mathbb P(\omega)$. (But please use @user to notify user of your comment.)